# PHP - How to detect if i'm growing or not?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stat

I create a website, i would like to know when i'm growing.

The idea is, i have a table

```
ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, STAMP
```

I would like to check, if yesterday i got a lot of new users than before yesterday, that means i'm growing, if before yesterday i got more than yesterday, that means i'm not growing.

A live exemple:

Before yesterday: 11 new users --- Yesterday: 14 new users

### UP

Before yesterday; 13 new users --- Yesterday: 9 new users

### DOWN

I like to echo UP if growing, DOWN if not.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Or maybe use a service such as [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) rather than trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you had a `DATE` column `registration_date` you could index on and `GROUP BY` for reporting purposes.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Google Analytics is pretty much useless for user-level analytics. It's better suited to high-level trends.

Comment: I have a Google Analytics account, i just try to see that in my system.

Comment: @tadman - Yea valid argument.  I use [Clicky](http://clicky.com/) for my site actually.  My point is there's like 3 million of these services for any sort of analysis you'd possibly want to do, so why spend the time writing your own unless it was purely a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

If `STAMP` represents the time the user joined you can run this query to find the number of users you got for each day.

```
SELECT DATE(STAMP), COUNT(*) AS users_joined FROM Users GROUP BY DATE(STAMP) ORDER BY STAMP DESC;
```

This will give you a table of all the users that joined for every day.  Then all you have to do is grab the first few rows and do the rest of your logic there!

**If you absolutely just want yesterday and the day before you can run**

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE STAMP = CURDATE()) as today,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE STAMP = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as yesterday, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE STAMP = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)) as day_before_yesterday;
```

Will result in a table like:

```
|-------|-----------|----------------------|
| today | yesterday | day_before_yesterday |
|-------|-----------|----------------------|
|  10   |    14     |         16           |
|-------|-----------|----------------------|
```

Comment: Probably `SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(STAMP)` so you could actually *see* which date each row represented.

Comment: Oh!  Yes, I forgot that part...  The GROUP/ORDER BY will fail without it.

Comment: how to set the variables for (yesterday results) AND (before yesterday results)

Comment: Well the resulting set will be in chronological order (from most recent to oldest)  So!  If you grab the first row, it will be the latest day you got users (which may or may not be the current day)

Comment: Well in PHP you can just use simple logic:
`$growing_today = ($today > $yesterday) ? "UP" : "DOWN";`
`$growing_yesterday = ($yesterday > $day_before_yesterday) ? "UP" : "DOWN";`  After that you want to also check for equality.
`if ($today == $yesterday) $growing_today = "NO CHANGE";`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a basic query of users in the db, then you can call mysql_numrows (or mysqli_num_rows) on your result to see how many there are.

Comment: that means i will need to do two mysql_query(), mysql_affected_rows() in each one, then devide ?

Comment: I'm not sue what you would divide or why... But once you found the rows for that day you could check it against the rows of the previous day. To my knowledge there's no way to save variables between sessions, so you could write them to a text file on your server or something